# Stacking of prepositions in English?

Tags: syntax, english, syntax-trees

*The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language* recognises the existence of intransitive prepositions (p. 612):

> The case for allowing prepositions with no complements is most compelling where the same word occurs either with or without an NP complement, as in *The owner is not in the house* ∼ *The owner is not in*. There are several reasons for saying that these two instances of in belong to the same category.
>
> Firstly, as illustrated in [7] of §1, the relation between the constructions with and without the NP complement is the same as is found with verbs, nouns, and adjectives: there is no more reason for saying that *in* here belongs to two different categories than for saying that *eating* does in She was eating an apple and She was eating, and so on. In
> particular, there is no functional difference between *in the house* and *in*, just as there is none between *eating an apple* and *eating*.
>
> Secondly, the same modifiers are permitted whether the NP complement is present or not. Compare:
>
> [26] ia. He’d left [two hours before the end]
>
> [26] ib. He’d left [two hours before].
>
> [26] iia. She went [straight inside the house]
> [26] iib. She went [straight inside].
>
> Thirdly, a considerable proportion of prepositions show a similar alternation between
> occurrence with NP and occurrence without. A sample of them is shown in [27].
>
> [27] aboard about above across after
> against along alongside apropos around
> before behind below beneath besides
> between beyond by down for
> in inside near notwithstanding off
> on opposite outside over past
> round since through throughout to
> under underneath up within without
>
> Most of these belong to the domains of space and time, predominantly the former, but there are a few with other meanings: apropos, besides, nothwithstanding, without. There is a good deal of variation with respect to how readily they occur without a complement. In, on, over, under, up, for example, are very common in this use, whereas *to* is restricted to secondary senses (He pulled the door to, “just not completely closed”; He came to, “recovered consciousness”; etc.), and the use of *against* and *for* without a complement
> is mainly restricted to contexts involving voting: We had a huge majority, with only two people voting against.
>
> Occurring with no NP complement is not a property found just occasionally with one or two prepositions, or only with marginal items. It is a property found systematically.throughout a wide range of the most central and typical prepositions in the language.

Taking what CGEL says to be true (though I welcome other analyses), then in the following sentence, the words 'down', 'there', and 'behind' are all prepositions.

> You'll find the supermarket down there behind the car park.

This is a sentence that has been uttered to me before by a tourist guide. When the guide uttered it to me, I did not think much of it, but upon reflecting on it, I am intrigued by its syntax. Unless my analysis is incorrect (a likely possibility), it seems that this sentence is characterised by 'prepositional stacking': the preposition 'down' is modified by 'there', which in turn is modified by 'behind the car park'. Is this a phenomenon in English, or is my analysis incorrect? And how would this be depicted in a tree diagram?

Many thanks.

Comment: So you're looking for specifically an analysis where "down" is a preposition in "down there"?

Comment: _Down_ and _behind_ are clearly Ps, but _there_ is a different class of word entirely, not a lexical item but a locative pronoun (unless you wanna say  _here, now,_ and _where_ are also prepositions).

Comment: @jlawler I seem to recall a post on Language Log that argued that both deictics like _(w/t)here_ and _now_ and days of the week are in fact prepositions. I didn’t fully buy it, if memory serves.

Comment: Just people trying to get as much mileage out of their terminology as they can before it becomes obsolete, while avoiding any old-fashioned terms that belong to different gangs.

Comment: @jlawler. There appears to be some disagreement amongst linguists as to the category of speech of 'there'. Under the analysis of CGEL, 'there' is an intransitive preposition used to express distal location (with both deictic and anaphoric uses). However, I have seen several authorities use other terminology. For instance, in his book *An Introduction to Syntax*, Robert D. van Valin Jr. subsumes both 'here'and 'there'under the category of 'locative demonstrative'. Moreover, although not linguistic bodies of reference, many dictionaries and English books classify 'there' as being an adverb. 1/2

Comment: This, I feel, has potentially led to some confusion as to how 'there' should be classified, as to what POS it belongs to. (2/2)

Comment: @jlawler The deictics *where, here, there, now, then* are all prepositions according to H&P, and the data is compelling. They're all modifiable by the specialist adverb *right* and not by *very,* they can postmodify nouns, they can function as locative complements of verbs like *be* and *put*, und so weiter.

Comment: @Eric *demonstrative* is not really a part of speech. It's a semantic label.

Comment: @Eric I think this is not a necessarily case of stacking so much as prepositions taking PP complements. So *down* takes a PP headed by *there.* I'm not certain, however, that *behind the car park* is a complement of *there.*

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'd expect the deictics, but I can't believe that anyone on LL argued that English days of the week were prepositions. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: H&P make a plausible case for dummy "there" being a pronoun and locative "there" being a preposition. They take the days of the week to be nouns, obviously.

Comment: Let's suppose that 'down' takes a PP complement headed by 'there'. That leaves two possible roles of the *behind* PP: either it independently modifies the NP 'the supermarket', or it is a modifier of 'there' (in which case down takes a PP headed by *there*, with the following *behind* PP modifying the head).

Comment: Isn't this all explained in CGEL? I don't have my copy to hand, but I recall that it is.

Comment: @Araucaria No, not certain. I can’t find the post now, and I’m not entirely sure they weren’t separate posts (perhaps not even both from Language Log). And to be fair, it was a bout _time adjuncts_, not days of the week specifically (_Monday_ is obviously a noun in “The 18th is a Monday”). But I’m fairly sure there was a post arguing that time adjuncts function like PPs, as in “He came home now/then/yesterday/Monday”. (The trouble there, of course, is that _now_ and _then_ can behave like adverbs as well: “He now/then came home” vs “*He yesterday came home”.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet CGEL treats "yesterday, today, tomorrow etc " as pronouns, thus in "He came home yesterday" an adjunct of temporal location realised by an NP with a deictic promoun as head.

Comment: @BillJ Perhaps that’s what I was remembering, and my hazy memory conflated the deictic prepositions and the temporal pronouns.